# Creating point in ArcPy to use in Select by Location query?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, select-by-location

I have a section grid for a US state. I also have a quarter/quarter section grid which splits the section grid into 16 equal squares.

I have written a Python script that finds the XY coordinates of the centroid of each quarter/quarter section, so 16 of them.

I need to create a temporary point feature at that centroid and then run a Select by Location on that point to see which quarter/quarter section it falls within and then I will be adding an attribute to that quarter/quarter section the point falls in.

How can I create this temporary point feature to be used in a Select by Location? Is there a way to create a single point in memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an example that used the Point geometry, for example:

```
point = arcpy.Point(x, y)
point_geom = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
```

Then you can use that in a Select by Location

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Layer", "CONTAINS", point_geom)
```